# where is the Live Services TAB gone on Windows Azure site?

Tags: azure, windows-live-id

I am trying to generate LiveID acess keys on the Azure Services Developer Portal but I cant find where the Live Services Tab is gone so I can retrieve the application id and secret key. Anyone have a similar experience and know where to get them now?
thanks guys

Edit:

I am using **Exercise 2 - Using Live ID Authentication** in the Azure Platform Kit Samples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that they ended up not including Live Services as part of the initial Windows Azure release - some of the various services were fairly half baked or incomplete.

I still managed to find the Live services pages again after some Googling - but even then, some of the services that used to be around (i.e. Windows Live Alerts) were missing.

Maybe you're looking at some older tutorials or samples?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN :
 [Getting Your Application ID for Delegated Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287659.aspx)

[Live Services Portal](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144070)